# Flutter - getting issues during app signing through flutter build command

Tags: flutter

I am following this link(https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) to generate signed build but getting following issues after running **flutter build appbundle**-

[image: terminal image]

**Note** - I am following all mentioned thing in that tutorial. The only difference is that i've placed file in app instead of android
My app/build.gradle is-

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
   localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
      localProperties.load(reader)
   }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
  throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk 
 in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
 if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
  flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
  keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 30

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true

}
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file("/home/user/xyz/gst.jks") 
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')
}
```

Comment: key.properties should be in android folder. and it would be better if you specify the keystore file location in the key.properties as well

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion  I was doing a mistake i.e. I was using wrong password and I don't why it was showing this error.

Comment: https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac , This process works for sure. You can refer this as well.